# typescript union in a class

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i'm learning ionic & angular. In this app i'm using the below class

**model.ts**

```
export class Feed {
  constructor(
    public type: string,
    public object: ReactionObject | ObituaryObject
  ) {}
}
export class ReactionObject {
  constructor(
    public actionId: string,
    public obituaryId: string,
    public categoryId: string,
    public timestamp: string,
    public userName: string,
    public userPhoto: string,
    public deceasedName: string,
    public thanked: string,
    public community: CommunityObject,
    public obituarySponsorId: string
  ) {}
}

export class ObituaryObject {
  constructor(
    public categoryId: string,
    public deathDay: string,
    public funeral: FuneralObject,
    public name: string,
    public obituaryId: number,
    public photo: string
  ) {}
}
```

**types.ts**

```
export interface ApiData {
  error: string;
  session_id: string;
  data: any;
  message?: string;
}
export interface FeedData extends ApiData {
  type: string;
  object: ReactionData | SingleObituaryData;
}
export interface ReactionData extends ApiData {
  actionId: string;
  obituaryId: string;
  categoryId: string;
  timestamp: string;
  userName: string;
  userPhoto: string;
  deceasedName: string;
  thanked: string;
  community: CommunityData;
  obituarySponsorId: string;
}
export interface SingleObituaryData extends ApiData {
  categoryId: string;
  deathDay: string;
  funeral: FuneralData;
  name: string;
  obituaryId: number;
  photo: string;
}
```

**feed.service.ts**

```
export class FeedService {
  private _feed = new BehaviorSubject<Feed[]>([]);

  get feed() {
    return this._feed.asObservable();
  }

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private http: HttpClient) {}

  getFeed(pageNumber: number) {
    return this.authService.userToken.pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap((token) => {
        return this.http.get<FeedData>(
          `${environment.apiURL}getFeed&token=${token}&page=${pageNumber}`
        );
      }),
      map((resData) => {
        resData = resData.data.items;
        console.log(resData);
        const feed = [];
        for (const key in resData) {
          if (resData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            feed.push(
              new Feed(
                resData[key].type,
                new ReactionObject(
                  resData[key].object.actionId,
                  resData[key].object.obituaryId,
                  resData[key].object.categoryId,
                  resData[key].object.timestamp,
                  resData[key].object.userName,
                  resData[key].object.userPhoto,
                  resData[key].object.deceasedName,
                  resData[key].object.thanked,
                  resData[key].object.community,
                  resData[key].object.obituarySponsorId,
                )
              )
            );
          }
        }
        return feed;
      }),
      tap((feed) => {
        this._feed.next(feed);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

**updates.component.html**

```
<p class="ion-text-center" *ngIf="!isLoading && loadedFeed.length <= 0">
  No updates found
</p>

<ion-list *ngIf="isLoading" class="ion-no-padding">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let i of Arr(num).fill(1)">
    <ion-avatar slot="start">
      <ion-skeleton-text animated></ion-skeleton-text>
    </ion-avatar>
    <ion-label>
      <p>
        <ion-skeleton-text animated style="width: 80%;"></ion-skeleton-text>
      </p>
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<ion-list *ngIf="!isLoading && loadedFeed.length > 0" class="ion-no-padding">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let feed of loadedFeed">
    <ng-container
      *ngIf="
        feed.type === 'candle' ||
        feed.type === 'flower' ||
        feed.type === 'comment'
      "
    >
      <ion-avatar slot="start">
        <img src="../../../assets/img/{{ feed.type }}-icon.svg" />
      </ion-avatar>
      <ion-label>
        {{ feed.object.userName }} // issue here
        <ng-container *ngIf="feed.type === 'candle'">
          lit a candle on
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="feed.type === 'flower'">
          placed a flower on
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="feed.type === 'comment'">
          wrote a message on
        </ng-container>
      </ion-label>
    </ng-container>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

i'm getting an error from VS code: `Identifier 'userName' is not defined. 'ReactionObject | ObituaryObject' does not contain such a member`
However this still does display the data correctly, also the IntelliSense shows only two options: *categoryId* & *obituaryId* which are common to both classes. Replacing `ObituaryObject` with `any` clears the error

Any ideas why i'm getting this error?

Thanks

Comment: Does the error persist with `feed.object['userName']`?

Comment: No, that removes the error :) but also i can't use IntelliSense

Comment: That is true. But TBH I don't rely too much on Intellisense in templates.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because in your **Feed** class you have the field **object** with two available tipes using the [Union Type](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-union).
The **ObituaryObject** does not have the field userName.

I would suggest to avoid the UnionType in favor of a father object using the [TypeScript inheritance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#inheritance).

Also your code in this way will be more clear.

### FULL WORKING CODE [HERE](https://github.com/GaetanoPiazzolla/stackoverflow-question-61697145).

### [Model](https://github.com/GaetanoPiazzolla/stackoverflow-question-61697145/blob/master/src/app/model/Model.ts) / [View](https://github.com/GaetanoPiazzolla/stackoverflow-question-61697145/blob/master/src/app/test/test.component.html) / [Component](https://github.com/GaetanoPiazzolla/stackoverflow-question-61697145/blob/master/src/app/test/test.component.ts)

Your model will become like :

```
export class GenObject {
  constructor(
    public obituaryId: number,
    public categoryId: string
  ) {
  }
}

export class Feed {
  constructor(
    public type: string,
    public object: GenObject
  ) {
  }
}

export class ReactionObject extends GenObject {
  constructor(
    public actionId: string,
    public userName: string,
    public obituaryId: number,
    public categoryId: string
  ) {
    super(obituaryId, categoryId);
  }
}

export class ObituaryObject extends GenObject {
  constructor(
    public deathDay: string,
    public name: string,
    public obituaryId: number,
    public categoryId: string
  ) {
    super(obituaryId, categoryId);
  }
}
```

Next, when accessing the field from the view, force the check to the specific class like this :

```
 {{ getReaction(obituaryObject.object).username }}
```

Having the method defined like this:

```
getReaction(object: GenObject) {
   if (object instanceof ReactionObject) {
     return object as ReactionObject;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> public object: ReactionObject | ObituaryObject
> ```

this defines that the `object` can be either of the types `ReactionObject` or `ObituaryObject`

> ```
>  {{ feed.object.userName }} // issue here
> ```

Change it to:

```
  {{ (feed.object as ReactionObject).userName }} // issue should be resolved.
```

or

```
  {{ (<ReactionObject>feed.object).userName }} // issue should be resolved.
```

Also add the import of the `ReactionObject` in `updates.component.ts

```
import { ReactionObject } from './model.ts'  // check the path for model.ts
```

**Update**:

In `updates.components.ts`, added a getter

```
get feedObjectUserName() { 
  return ( <RectionObject> feed.object).userName
}
```

and in `updates.component.html`, changed to

```
{{ feedObjectUserName }}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you share the error? You can even try using `{{ (<ReactionObject>feed.object).userName }}`

Comment: the first solution was giving me this error `Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 15 in [
        {{ (feed.object as ReactionObject).userName }}
        ]`

the second solution is giving this error `'ReactionObject' is not a known element:
1. If 'ReactionObject' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.`

Comment: The first error is probably due to some typo. However, the second error needs to be fixed. `import { ReactionObject } from 'model.ts'` <--- please check the path and add it in the `updates.component.ts`

Comment: imported the model.ts and still have the same error

Comment: try using a getter: In `updates.components.ts`, add `get feedObjectUserName() { return (<RectionObject>feed.object).userName }` and change in `updates.component.html` to `{{ feedObjectUserName }}`

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. If my answer was useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped.